# Insert mode's CTRL-E and CTRL-Y vs popup menu

Tags: popup-menu

I was wandering that sometimes I'd like <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd> to work even while I'm in insert mode. Before setting up any mapping I thought I should see if I'm shadowing some important functionality, so I searched for `:h i_CTRL-E` and discovered these two functionalities of <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd> in insert mode. I didn't know of them, nor I can think of how they could come useful to me.

Experimenting with them, I've noticed that <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> is interrupted by the appearence of the pop up menu (which for comes up with YCM), but <kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd> isn't.

So I was wandering,

- Is the fact that the pum prevents  <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> from working something avoidable?
- Why this asymmetry between <kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-Y</kbd>, the former being interrupted by pum and not the latter?
- (Offtopic) Is anybody using those two insert mode commands?

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Good question re. practical use for these two commands. Except for a few Vim Golf questions :) I've personally not come across anything yet despite being aware of them for a pretty long time. There's gotta be _something_ that they are good for beyond the very occasional, basically random happenstance of needing to copy a couple characters from an adjacent line (personally I'd just type them...just as fast).

Comment: If I forget to `yyp` to make modifications to lines, and I'm already in insert mode, I might use one of them. I try to use C-X C-L more, but these C-y and C-e work better when the start doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that something avoidable?

What is "avoidable"? `<C-E>` normally escapes from pum; `<C-Y>` accepts pum selection. But you can remap both (probably with check against `:h pumvisible()`) if required.

> Why this asymmetry

In fact, they are quite symmetric to each other: copy from up/down line in insert mode; or cancel/accept pum if it's visible.

> Is anybody using those two insert mode commands?

Me. From time to time.

Comment: I've just clarified the question

Comment: @Enlico I still don't understand. `<C-E>` always works. It just does different things depending on pum is visible or not.

Comment: yeah, but I didn't know it was meant to do something different when pum is visible, hence my question.